# Can I make a ListView unscrollable and expanded on a screen with multiple ListViews?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

This is a screen on my app: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfn2f94mz2ibeay/Screenshot_2013-12-02-13-30-10.png

For demoing purposes, is it possible to not have the bottom ListView be scrollable and expand completely instead? I don't know how to get the "Other Games" tab like the way I have it (I used 3 LinearLayouts, 2 for the bar and 1 for the title) if I made everything into one ListView, so I made 2 ListViews instead. Ideally, I want both ListViews to be unscrollable and completely expanded and only the entire view be scrollable. Is there a quick fix?

Thanks!

Comment: are you talking about `listView` or `expandable listview` at the end of the screen?

Comment: And why don't you implement `my balance` and `other games` in two different `sliding tabs`?